# How to prevent $error from collecting caught exceptions?

Tags: powershell, try-catch

Whenever I catch an exception and handle it, it still seems to end up inside the `$error` variable. For example, use the following code as a sample repro:

```powershell
$error.clear(); # To make the example as clear as possible

# Lots of logic happens here that leaves a trace in $error. I want to see these
# traces at the very end of my script. However, before the end, seomething along
# these lines happens:

try {
    Write-Output "Trying...";
    $myVar = $null; # Assume $null is actually the result of a complex function
    if ($myVar.ToString() -match "my pattern") {
        # More logic here
    }
} catch {
    Write-Output "Catching...";
} 

# Even more stuff happens here, which may (or may not) add interesting stuff to
# the $error variable.

# Here, at the end of my script, I'm only interested in errors *not* from the 
# try..catch bit, but alas, the Count will inlcude those too...
Write-Output ("Ending... with error.Count = {0}" -f $error.Count);
```

The error is caught, but the `$error.Count` is still "1" at the end of this script. However, in my case I'm handling the error inside the `catch` and I don't want to be bothered by the error at the end of my script.

I've tried to rewrite the logic causing the exception to a commandlet, hoping the `ErrorAction` parameter would solve something, but that didn't work.

I've also tried my Google-fu (various variations on [this query](https://www.google.nl/search?q=powershell%20catch%20prevent%20exception%20from%20getting%20into%20$error)) and SO-fu (variations on [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D%20try%20catch%20%24error%20is%3Aq)) but they turned up empty.

Before I close, let me elaborate on the context for my scenario, in case I'm experiencing an XY-problem. The above snippet is a representation of a small bit of code in a longer deployment script. Before and after that block of code there may be other things that leave a trace inside the `$error` variable. For this reason I think I cannot clear the errors at the start (I want to keep things that may already be in there).

Bottom line: how can I prevent the `$error` variable from gathering caught exceptions?

Comment: Could you not just do a `$error.clear` again in something like a `finally` block

Comment: I don't think you can prevent this behavior. But out of curiosity, why does it bother you? If you catch the exceptions yourself, you don't have to deal with $error at all.

Comment: Hey @Matt, thanks for your comment. I've added some context to the question to address it. Basically, when the mentioned block is executed, the `$error` variable may already be populated with things I want to keep there.

Comment: Oh. You are trying to move errors that have been addressed but still want to know what you may have missed over your codes execution.

Comment: @ojk Does my previous comment also hope to address your question? To elaborate I'm interested in the `$error` variable because of what happened *before* my script block. I want to prevent my `try...catch` from cluttering that variable. (If the answer's "That's not possible" then so be it, of course - that would just require me to rethink my setup.)

Comment: The only thing I can come up with then, is to do a clear at the beginning of the script (as you have done), and before a try-catch, save the $error into $myErrors or something, and do a new clear after the try-catch. If you know what I mean? Then you would get any script errors, not handled by you explicitly.

Comment: @ojk Yes, that makes sense, I could try that. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: like Matt allready said you can not change this behavior, all exceptions will allways be added to `$error`, regardless of the erroraction defined

Comment: I could think of two ways to cheat this. Keep a separate count of errors addressed. But i get why that wouldnt really work. Other thing to do would be to keep a separate object collection of your `$error[0]`'s for a comparison at the end of the script. I am toying with that idea now.

Answer (score 0):

I will delete this if it not what you are looking for but I tried to do something like this. It has a caveat which you might see on your own that I will address.

```
$error.clear()
$addressedErrors = @()

Get-ChildItem c:\tempo1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

try{
    Get-ChildItem c:\tempo2 -ErrorAction Stop
} Catch {
    $addressedErrors += [regex]::escape($error[0].Exception.Message)
}
Get-ChildItem c:\tempo3 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue


$regex = "($($addressedErrors -join '|'))"
$uncaughtErrors = $error | Where-Object{$_.Exception.Message -notmatch $regex}

$uncaughtErrors.Count
```

So I clear the `$error` to start from a clean slate. In my test I executed 3 `Get-ChildItem` that are supposed to fail. I only capture the one.

Within the `Catch` I take the error message and build and array of those messages. Also use the static `escape` regex method to escape regex special characters. I considered taking the actuak exception, in this case [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException], but that wasnt unique enough for me to trust the approach.

At the end of my/your script I take the collection of error messages and build a regex string. Take the `$error` object and output the errors that were not already addressed.

**Caveat**

One thing that I know would be wrong in doing this is if the exact same erorr occured twice but addressed once. The `-notmatch` would filter out both occurances. Could fix that by building a complex hash table with erorr indexes but I dont know if you are even commited to this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I use the method of `$Error.RemoveAt(0)` in my catch block to help with this.
I find myself using this in Scheduled tasks where I check the count of $Error and throw an exit code if we hit any non handed exceptions.

The zero in `$Error.RemoveAt(0)` is the index number, essentially removing the latest error. This should hopefully remove the error that sent you to the catch block.

```
try {
    $FormattedDate = Get-Date -Date $Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd" -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    $Error.RemoveAt(0)
    $FormattedDate = $null
}
```